# Implementing Container above Draggable Bottomsheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, draggable, bottom-sheet

How do I add that small container above the draggable bottomsheet in Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Sliding up Panel Package  .... Or If you want to use BottomSheet then will return One main Widget Which Would be Container ,let say you have set it's height to MediaQuery..>height   then the Child of this Container Would a Column() widget Which would contains 2 widget one is Container for Image or simply give it width of 20.0 and height of 8.0 etc and the Other widget would be Another Container for the rest of the Page

Comment: Does it help you ?

Comment: Not really. Sliding up panel doesn't really do what I am looking for. Did you see the little box I circled in red in the image. That's the kind of thing I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap scrollable widget with Flexible. Now wrap this flexible with Column and place ur asset a 1st child. Give this Column desired size.

```
        Container(
          margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
          child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
            onNotification:
                (DraggableScrollableNotification DSNotification) {
              if (FAB_visibility && DSNotification.extent >= 0.2) {
                setState(() {
                  FAB_visibility = false;
                });
              } else if (!FAB_visibility &&
                  DSNotification.extent < 0.2) {
                setState(() {
                  FAB_visibility = true;
                });
              }
              print('FAB_visibility: ${FAB_visibility}');
              return true;
            },
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: 0.13,
              minChildSize: 0.13,
              maxChildSize: 0.7,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  ScrollController scrollController) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 500.0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        AppImages.ic_tooltip_arrow,
                        color: DarkTheme.appBarContainer,
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        // height: 500.0,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            controller: scrollController,
                            child: Obx(() => vehicleDetailsController
                                        .vehicleMode.value.customerAddress !=
                                    null
                                ? modalSheetBody(vehicleDetailsController
                                    .vehicleMode.value)
                                : SizedBox())),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).